# Multiply each other value in row with first value in row

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
Date <- c("04.06.2013","05.06.2013","06.06.2013","07.06.2013","08.06.2013","09.06.2013")
 discharge <- c("1000","2000","1100","3000","1700","1600")
 concentration_1 <- c("25","20","11","6.4","17","16")
 concentration_2 <- c("1.4","1.7","2.7","3.2","4","4.7")
 concentration_3 <- c("1.2","1.3","1.9","2.2","2.4","3")
 concentration_4 <- c("1","0.92","2.5","3","3.4","4.8")

y <- data.frame(Date, discharge,concentration_1,concentration_2,concentration_3,concentration_4, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
y$Date <- as.Date(y$Date, format ="%d.%m.%Y")
y[-1] <- sapply(y[-1], as.numeric)
```

In each row, I need to multiply each concentration with the discharge. 
I was looking into the `apply` function but couldn´t figure out how to solve it.

Comment: why do you put the concentrations and discharge value as character (which then become factor when put in a data.frame without defining `stringsAsFactors` as FALSE)?

Comment: True...corrected my example

Comment: if the data are in correct format (i.e. numeric), just do `y[, 3:6] <- lapply(y[, 3:6], `*`, y$discharge)` or even just `y[, 3:6]*y$discharge` (rigth part will be rightly recycle)

Comment: @Matt `ncol(y)` gives the number of columns

Comment: @Cath Would there be a way to let R detect how many columns I have, say `y[, 3:???]´?

Comment: `y[,3:ncol(y)]`

Comment: @Cath How can I keep the discharge column in the resulting data frame?

Comment: @Matt as Ryan said, `ncol(y)` gives you the number of columns. If the columns of interest are not necessarily the last ones but have same kind of name, you can also use `grep`: `grep("^concentration", colnames(y))`

Comment: `y[, 3:ncol(y)] <- y[, 3:6]*y$discharge` will keep all columns in `y`, you're just modifying the third to last ones

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No `apply` needed, just multiply. But first let's get your data in decent shape.

They way you define your data, because you use quotes around the numbers, all the columns that should be numeric are factors. We use `lapply` to convert them safely to numeric:

```
y <- data.frame(Date, discharge,concentration_1,concentration_2,concentration_3,concentration_4)
y$Date <- as.Date(y$Date, format ="%d.%m.%Y")
str(y)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ Date           : Date, format: "2013-06-04" "2013-06-05" "2013-06-06" "2013-06-07" ...
#  $ discharge      : Factor w/ 6 levels "1000","1100",..: 1 5 2 6 4 3
#  $ concentration_1: Factor w/ 6 levels "11","16","17",..: 5 4 1 6 3 2
#  $ concentration_2: Factor w/ 6 levels "1.4","1.7","2.7",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
#  $ concentration_3: Factor w/ 6 levels "1.2","1.3","1.9",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
#  $ concentration_4: Factor w/ 6 levels "0.92","1","2.5",..: 2 1 3 4 5 6

# convert all columns but the first safely to numeric
y[, -1] = lapply(y[, -1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
str(y)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ Date           : Date, format: "2013-06-04" "2013-06-05" "2013-06-06" "2013-06-07" ...
#  $ discharge      : num  1000 2000 1100 3000 1700 1600
#  $ concentration_1: num  25 20 11 6.4 17 16
#  $ concentration_2: num  1.4 1.7 2.7 3.2 4 4.7
#  $ concentration_3: num  1.2 1.3 1.9 2.2 2.4 3
#  $ concentration_4: num  1 0.92 2.5 3 3.4 4.8
```

With that done, we can just multiply the concentration columns by the discharge column. R will "recycle" the discharge column to multiply each of the concentration columns appropriately.

```
concentration_columns = paste0("concentration_", 1:4)
y[, concentration_columns] = y[, concentration_columns] * y[, "discharge"]
y
#        Date discharge concentration_1 concentration_2 concentration_3 concentration_4
# 1 2013-06-04      1000           25000            1400            1200            1000
# 2 2013-06-05      2000           40000            3400            2600            1840
# 3 2013-06-06      1100           12100            2970            2090            2750
# 4 2013-06-07      3000           19200            9600            6600            9000
# 5 2013-06-08      1700           28900            6800            4080            5780
# 6 2013-06-09      1600           25600            7520            4800            7680
```

Comment: What if the concentration columns don´t have the same prefix but all different names and I want R let detect the number of columns instead of `[1:4]`?

Comment: Then do something like `concentration_index = grep(pattern = "concentration", names(y))` or `concentration_names = names(y)[grepl(pattern = "concentration", names(y))]`. You can adjust the `pattern` argument to use a regex that's as specific as it needs to be.

Comment: Or even `grep(., value = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2):

The multiplication is vectorized, just use the columns you want to multiply as operands.

```
y[, 2] * y[, -(1:2)]
```

Comment: vectorisation helps that each element of a column is multiplied by each element of the vector (`discharge`) but it's thanks to `recycling` (of the `discharge` vector) that we don't need `lapply`

Answer (score 0):

Once your values as not character (not in ""), you can use apply like this:

```
   new <- data.frame(y[,1:2],apply(y[,3:6],2,function(x) x*y$discharge))
```

Comment: better use `lapply` on a `data.frame`, `apply` coerces the `data.frame` to a `matrix`